# Incorrect grouping of data in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to group the employees by Emp Code. It works if there is more than 1 record for an employee but if there is < 1 it doesn't work. Like line 13 and 14. This should have been seperate

I have this code:

```
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim customernumber As Integer

    counter = 2
    customernumber = 2

    Do While Worksheets("Mini").Cells(counter, 1).Value <> ""

    Worksheets("Mini").Cells(counter, 4).Value = "Testing the Do While"
    Worksheets("Mini").Cells(counter, 5).Value = customernumber + 1


If Worksheets("Mini").Cells(counter, 1).Value <> z Then
          
            z = Worksheets("Mini").Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value

                 
                
                 With Worksheets("Mini").rows(counter - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThick
                    
                    Worksheets("Mini").Cells(counter, 5).Value = 1
                    customernumber = 0
                    
                 End With
                 
                
End If
```

How can I change it?

Below is a image of the sheet

[image: Sheet]

Comment: Please post functioning code.  In what you show, you are missing a `Loop` statement, and you never increment Counter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set z before the IF test.

```
  Dim counter As Integer
  Dim customernumber As Integer
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim z As Long
  
  Set wks = Worksheets("Mini")
  
  counter = 2
  customernumber = 2

  With wks
  
  Do While .Cells(counter, 1).Value <> ""

    .Cells(counter, 4).Value = "Testing the Do While"
    .Cells(counter, 5).Value = customernumber + 1
      
    z = .Cells(counter + 1, 1).Value

     If .Cells(counter, 1).Value <> z Then
                               
                 With .rows(counter - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                     .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                     .Weight = xlThick
                      
                     wks.Cells(counter, 5).Value = 1
                     customernumber = 0
                    
                 End With
  
     End If
     
     counter = counter + 1
     
  Loop
```